# Vim/MacVim: when I scroll with mouse, the text cursor moves too!

Tags: vim, text, selection, macvim

I've been getting used to Vim/MacVim for the last few weeks. One of main problems I seem to be having is when I scroll around using the mouse (especially when I'm trying to select large portions of text) the text insertion cursor moves too and doesn't stay where it was (like in TextMate for example). This means I've selected a large piece of text, when I scroll back up to review my selection the cursor will move which messes with the selection that I've made.

I do realise I should get used to text selection with visual mode, and I am one bit of a time, but sometimes it's the best tool to use the mouse.

Is there a way of fixing this behaviour?

Comment: Don't know but you should definitly use visual mode, <shift>+v to select line, then you can use 'o' to review your selection... worth learning even if you loose time first !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:help scrolling` tells you:

> These commands move the contents of
>   the window.  If the cursor position is
>   moved off of the window, the cursor is
>   moved onto the window (with
>   'scrolloff' screen lines around it).

So basically I would say that it is not possible to leave the cursor where it was when you are scrolling. The cursor is always visible in your window, and therefore your visual selection will extend.

Probably you would like to `xnoremap <ScrollWheelUp> <esc><ScrollWheelUp>` and same for ScrollWheelDown. Use then `gv` to restore your selection.

Comment: I almost love VIM. There is a few issues though. It looks like PyCharm with VIM bindings could be the best of both worlds.

Comment: The problem is that Vim is a power editor and it is more efficient to use a keyboard than a mouse for virtually every task, so when you try to use a mouse to do a keyboard's job, Vim is having none of that.

Answer (score 3):

I made a screencast about [Vim's changelist and jumplist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-the-changelist-and-jumplist/) which addresses the issue of Vim's cursor always being on screen. The changelist maintains a list of all of the places in your document where you have made an edit. You can move back and forward through the list with the commands `g;` and `g,` respectively. Or if you want to put your cursor back on the last place where you made an edit and go into insert mode, just press `gi`.

As Alois Cochard pointed out, the `o` key is very useful when you are in visual mode. It moves the cursor between the start and the beginning of your selection. So if your selection is larger than your screen, it will move you from one end to the other.